# mysql - how do I use the same table in an inner and outer query?

Tags: mysql

consider the following table

| id | class | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 20 |
| 1 | B | 50 |
| 1 | C | 30 |
| 1 | TOTAL | 100 |

I need to generate a column that is the percentage each class contributes to the effort

something like

```
select Y/(select Y from table where class = 'TOTAL') 
from table 
group by id
```

but how do I pass the id to the inner query?

Comment: use an [alias](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#:~:text=be%20given%20an-,alias,-using%20AS%20alias_name)

Comment: What's your expect result I think you might modify your store design

Answer (score 0):

With aliases you will get something like:

```
select 
   t1.Y/(select t2.Y from table1 t2 where t2.class = 'TOTAL') 
from table1 t1
group by t1.id
```

But this will produce the following error (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50244b8c54ba5c16354c447ebdd218a2):

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
> nonaggregated column 'db_1321975282.t1.Y' which is not functionally
> dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I think this is what you meant to do, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d06d53ac5148530ff7f1c4aa0c8a276):

```
select 
   t1.Y/t2.sumY
from table1 t1
cross join (select sum(y) as sumY from table1 where class='TOTAL') t2
```

In this query `t1`,`t2` and `sumY` are aliases.

output:

| t1.Y/t2.sumY |
| --- |
| 0.2000 |
| 0.5000 |
| 0.3000 |
| 1.0000 |